# Convert file.Inputstream to UTF-8 c#

Tags: c#, encoding, utf-8

I am working on a csv import and am receiving a file which is western european encoded. There are certain charachters like ü which are showing up incorrectly.
However when I save the file as UTF-8 encoded , it works fine.
Is there any way I can encode the file I receive as an upload to convert it into UTF-8
? Using CSVHelper to parse CSV

```
  ICsvParser csvParser = new CsvParser(new StreamReader(stream));

  CsvReader csvReader = new CsvReader(csvParser);

  while (csvReader.Read())
        {
          .. do something
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `new StreamReader(stream, Encoding.GetEncoding("windows-1252"))` if the file is encoded in western encoding.